# Date conversion from string to timestamp using php

Tags: php

How could i convert this string "03/16/2012 03:22PM"using php to store in datetime format in mysql, i.e "2012-03-16 15:22:00" (add 00 as default in sec).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime("03/16/2012 03:22PM"));
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/7OQwgMle)

Answer (score 0):

`$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("03/16/2012 03:22"));`